# How do I check if a product is configurable

Tags: configurable-product, products

Does someone know how to check if a product is **configurable** ?

I want my configurable products to say 'From:' in front of the price on the product list page.

Comment: Please specify which Magento version you are using.

Comment: this one I believe your question can be answered through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968361/how-to-check-if-a-product-is-a-simple-product/

Comment: Found answer here?

Answer (score 20):

From the question it is not clear for which version you want to check still I am adding answer,

For `M2` you can check like this,

```
if($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE){
          echo "product is configurable";
}
```

Where `$product` is `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` object

---

For `M1` you can check like this,

```
if($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::TYPE_CODE){
          echo "product is configurable";
}
```

Where `$product` is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` object

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I find the first simple product for a configurable product inside the if statement?

Answer (score 4):

For configurable product check product type ID using simple code.

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'){
     echo 'This is a configurable product';
}else{
     echo 'This is not a configurable product';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I like your suggestion. Could you please tell me how can I find the first simple product for a configurable product inside the first if statement?

Answer (score 1):

For `M1` you can use:

```
/* Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
if ($product->isConfigurable()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I find the first simple product for a configurable product inside the if statement?